# The specified view already has a parent - Android ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am currently trying to understand an exception which suddently appeared when everything was working. I have a ViewPager and two fragments, and I am calling a camera intent in one of them. When the intent is finished, the application crashes:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14095): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call
removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Here is my onCreateView code:

```
switch (index) {
case 1:
    rootView = frag_capture(rootView, inflater, container);
    break;
case 2:
    rootView = frag_notepad(rootView, inflater, container);
    break;
}
```

And in the corresponding functions:

```
int resId = R.layout.<corresponding fragment>;

rootView = inflater.inflate(resId, container, false);
((ViewPager) container).addView(rootView, 0);
```

I guess the addView is wrong, but can't find how to correct it.

Edit:

```
 public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        if (observer != null) {
            super.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
        }
    }

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use an adapter with the viewpager

Comment: This code was from my inner class PlaceholderFragment. This is in my activity onCreate method:
    `mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);`

Comment: but then why are you calling viewpager.addView? The adapter takes care of it

Comment: because when I don't put it, the application crashes directly at the start

Comment: *the application crashes directly at the start*: What kind of exception? Can you post the adapter?

Comment: It crashes because of a NPE, due to a findViewById returning null: a fragment problem

Answer (score 0):

I found out I had lost a part of the code and took it back from the repository, but this wasn't the only problem.

Some functions I used where using the current view instead of "rootView" from the fragment. I added a parameter to use it in each of these functions and it worked.

Also, this device had a recent new security application which blocked media capture and made my application crash. When I deactivated, it worked well again.

Thank you for your answers, it made me correct an old bug that was bothering me on only one particular device but was very annoying.